# React Native: Placing image into existing PDF at specific X,Y

Tags: android, react-native, pdf, pdf-generation, pdf-manipulation

I am currently working on react-native app, where I would like to place image into existing pdf at specific coorinates.

Firstly, I create PDF from HTML template with the following library, and at this point, I also create a space (let's say some X mark - I dont know the exact coordinates, it depends on PDF length) for image which will be potentialy added after a while:

[react-native-html-to-pdf](https://github.com/christopherdro/react-native-html-to-pdf)

For PDF manipulation I am using this library (you have to define x, y coordinate where to place an image):

[react-native-pdf-lib](https://github.com/Hopding/react-native-pdf-lib)

So I am asking, if is there a way to somehow determine where is this place (mark X) in the existing PDF.

Comment: seems odd that you would have to do that. i would image as your build it into a PDF, line by line, it will output in that format? have you tried? if you tried, maybe posting code instead of links would be better.

Comment: Yes I can do this before but this is not the case.. This pdf is created at some time and after a while (days, weeks) the image will be inserted on top. If I I wont find a different way, I will regenerate it, but perfecly it would be to just modify existing PDF